# How can i get data packet from client c#?

Tags: c#, sockets

i want to use this code into button click event c#:

```
byte[] input = BitConverter.GetBytes(1);
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
s.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(strIP), 80));
s.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, input, null);
int bytes;
bytes = s.Receive(buffer);
while (bytes > 0)
{
    log(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));
    bytes = s.Receive(buffer);
}
```

my question is there:
i put the my server address into the strIP?and how can i use this line?

```
log(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));
```

or how can i show my data into the label?or i want to when i click the button show me data packet into the label.

Answer (score 0):

> i put the my server address into the strIP?

Yes, you put your server ip address into that string.

> and how can i use this line?

Like this:

```
Label1.text = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes);
```